# Rewrite iisnode web.config to allow github server through plesk

Tags: git, url-rewriting, plesk, iisnode

I can use no rewrite entries in the web.config, and I can access and use  /plesk-git/app.git just fine, externally and through the browser. But when I apply the rewrite code:

```
<clear />
<rule name="app">
 <match url="/*" />
 <action type="Rewrite" url="server/app.js" />
</rule>
```

I can no longer make changes to the git repo, repository not found error. How can I allow the git path to be excluded from this wildcard rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just found a solution.
Attaching a condition to the rule, allowed me to make an exception if the url piece was prefixed with /plesk-git/*, as such:

```
<conditions>
  <add input="{URL}" pattern="/plesk-git/*" negate="true"/>
</conditions>
```